# Bootstrap btn group vertical text alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a btn group for the 10 steps of a configuration process.

Here is a sample of what I have currently.
http://pixelneering.com/progress-steps.html

Options 4, 5 and 9 are only 1 line, and thus being aligned in the middle. I am trying to make all options vertical-align: top; but none of the elements respond to that.

So the HTML I have, standard btn group

```
<div class="btn-group hidden-xs" style="margin: 9px 0;">
  <button class="btn btn-steps"><span class="step-number">1</span><span class="step-description">Contact<br>Information</span></button>
  <button class="btn btn-steps"><span class="step-number">2</span><span class="step-description">Standard<br>Specifications</span></button>
  <button class="btn btn-steps"><span class="step-number">3</span><span class="step-description">Compressor Frame<br>& Cylinders</span></button>
  <button class="btn btn-steps"><span class="step-number">4</span><span class="step-description">Driver<br></span></button>
  <button class="btn btn-steps"><span class="step-number">5</span><span class="step-description">Air Cooler<br></span></button>
  <button class="btn btn-steps"><span class="step-number">6</span><span class="step-description">Controls, Instrumentation<br>& Wiring</span></button>
  <button class="btn btn-steps"><span class="step-number">7</span><span class="step-description">Vessels <br>& Piping</span></button>
  <button class="btn btn-steps"><span class="step-number">8</span><span class="step-description">Process Gas Valves<br>& Accessories</span></button>
  <button class="btn btn-steps"><span class="step-number">9</span><span class="step-description">Miscellaneous<br></span></button>
  <button class="btn btn-steps"><span class="step-number">10</span><span class="step-description">Configuration<br> Summary</span></button>
</div>
```

And the CSS for the btn-steps

```
    .btn-steps {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 11px;
  min-height: 50px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  border-color: #eeeeee;
  color: #333;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
  background-color: #e4e4e4;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#eeeeee,#d5d5d5);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#eeeeee),to(#d5d5d5));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#eeeeee,#d5d5d5);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#eeeeee,#d5d5d5);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#eeeeee,#d5d5d5);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffeeeeee', endColorstr='#ffd4d4d4', GradientType=0);
  border-color: #d5d5d5 #d5d5d5 #aeaeae;
  border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
}
```

This should be a simple CSS fix, but I am clearly missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `button` is a [Replaced Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element) it's outside the scope of CSS. And the content of a button is always centered. You may be able to change that in a hackish way. But for your needs it would be the best to make `<a>` tags out of your buttons. See this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v9oLtq4e/

Comment: You can (and in many cases should) style `<button>` `<a>` and `<input type="button" />` with very few minor differences/issues with older browsers. All of these elements have their appropriate context.

Comment: You can style a `button`, but not in the same way as an `a` tag. Hopefully this link makes it more clear http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/replacedelements

Comment: You have to add more styles to make all of those elements consistant, but you should be able to add a class to any of those three elements and have them look the same. The class should control your styles, not the element.

Comment: I didn't add any style myself and don't think there is a need for, cause the question was to align the content to top, what the `a` tag is doing natively. I'm totally with you, if you say: CSS should do the styling. But it's a hardliner thing not to change the HTML markup at all, even if it makes sence. Anyway, if you know a better solution, I would be excited to know!

Comment: @Sarower I didn't even know you had that problem. But it was a pleasure to help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want them vertically aligned to the middle, simply remove the height from your `span` elements within each button.  When the element is set to the size of its container, it's (by necessity) already vertically aligned.

Keep in mind that `vertical-align` refers to the element alignment, and not the text alignment within the element.  If you're looking for that style behavior, you may want to check out `display: table-cell` but I don't think that's worked for a while to achieve vertical-alignment of text.

If you want the reverse, simply give the `span` elements within the `button` the height equal to the container.  Text flow will force the elements to begin at the top, and thus you've achieved your vertical alignment.

In the case of a constrained element (such as yours), this is an easily solvable problem.  It becomes more difficult when the content is dynamic, though not terribly difficult.